# Get the URL of the previous page even after history.back() event

Tags: javascript, url, browser-history

Is there a way I can get the URL of the last page the user has been? `document.referrer` isn't what I want, because it only gets the referrer and it won't work if, for instance, the user clicks the back button.

I suspect this isn't possible, since you can't even get the URL of the forward page in the history.

Comment: The previous page is in your site/app, right ? If yes, you can do.

Comment: You can't do that for security reasons (would allow people to edit pages, create fake forms, etc. where information can be stolen - like someone's ID, banking information, etc.), unless as @DontVoteMeDown suggested, it is hosted by you. Here is a good topic post on the matter: http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=31256

Comment: @ctwheels I think #7 might do what I want. I'll look more closely into it later, but thanks.

Comment: @Romário if you solve your own answer, post it here as an answer and accept it in case future users have the same question, that way they can see your question and can find a working answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @ctwheels, this seems to solve my problem: http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=31256&p=169916

Quoting from the page:

> get the url of just the last previous page? of your domain only, or
>   all previous pages? of yours and external domains?
>
> if you require last previous page, of your domain only, would storing
>   url in javascript cookie work?
>
> one cookie to store previous url, and another to store current, then
>   next page, the current would become the previous.

EDIT: @DontVoteMeDown recommended to use localStorage instead of cookies.

Comment: Don't use cookies, use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)